# Run EVM Code outside the Blockchain

Tags: remix, evm, bytecode

is there any way to execute functions on a smart contract (as EVM-Bytecode) in a separate program like evm (provided by go-ethereum) without having to run a test-network? I need to find a way to run code multiple times so using Remix is unfortunately no option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at truffle, their aim is to make ethereum development easier.

Comment: Hi there. What's the issue with running things multiple times in Remix? Why do you want to be able to run it multiple times, and how many times are we talking about? (Clarifying things might help with an answer.)

Comment: I wanted to run functions on a smart contract multiple times for testing purposes to trace bugs. Using Remix I would need to start each call manually and Web3 w/ testrpc would be too slow.

Answer (score 4):

[Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) and [Ganache](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/) seem to be an excellent combo:

- Ganache is a standalone, in-memory node, designed for development. It can auto-mine, meaning it immediately creates and mine a block each time a transaction is submitted. This make smart contract deployment and invocation almost synchronous.
- Truffle comes with a command line tool and console with web3 built-in, removing some of the hassle of web3 setup.
- Truffle lets you write [JavaScript tests](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests) for your contracts using Mocha and Chai. Definitely the right way to run your contracts "multiple times" :)

Answer (score 2):

For whom it may interests, I used the build-in EVM of the Go-Ethereum implementation (Geth). For that I wrote my application in go and mainly used "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/vm/runtime" and github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/vm" as imports. To generate a EVM-instance I used *runtime.Config and *vm.EVM. Then I used a modified version of the Create- and Call-functions demonstrated in [..]runtime/runtime.go to deploy contracts and call transactions.

Comment: I wonder if you could link the edited code of these two files you used. That would help me a lot for my researches :D